# Adobe Acrobat PDF Date format issues

Tags: date, pdf, adobe

PDF date format:

[image]

The date field is being populated by a power automate flow and the formula for sent date is:

```
convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','Eastern Standard Time','MM-dd-yyyy')
```

However, when the flow is run and the agreement is sent out the date appears like so

[image]

The month always appears as 0 but when I click on the date and it appears accurately.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the formatting from the formula resolved the issue

Formula used:

```
convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','Eastern Standard Time')
```

seems trivial now.